# Setting DISPLAY variable on a remote XServer session

Tags: bash, centos, x-server, x2go

I have a CentOS system running an `X2go server` and I use a client machine to connect to it. I'm trying to do some command-line automation for mouse-clicks using `xdotool`. The automation is scripted in bash and is placed in `/etc/profile.d`. The idea is when any user logs into `X2go server` from a client, the automation script should execute.

However, there is one issue with this approach. For `xdotool`, a `Xserver` session is needed. On further digging, I found that there is no display variable set when the session initiates and therefore the script fails (`xdotool`). It takes about 30 seconds for the `XSession` to fully establish before a display variable is set. I cannot simply add a `sleep` in the bash script at it delays the login process since the script resides in `/etc/profile.d`.

Any neat way to tacke this?

Comment: The clean way is not to confuse shell initialization (various `profile`), which gets executed for *every single shell that is started*, with **session** initialization. Originally, X session managers and display managers all had places where to put those session initialization scripts (often variants of `Xsession`), but newer ones tend to skimp on those features. I am not familiar with X2go, so you can try to look through the docs (which on first sight don't have details) and see if X2go allows that.

Comment: If you need the `X` session to be setup, then the automation script should go inside `.xsession`.